# Vertical alignment of figure in a tabular. (Automatic width)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align photos and text vertically and horizontally in the middle of each tabular. I've tried the 'array' package but it seems like I need to define the width of the column. I want the column to be adjusted by max length of any object.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
        &                   $\downarrow$                   &              \\
        $\rightarrow$ & \rule{4cm}{4cm} & $\leftarrow$ \\
        &                    $\uparrow$                    &
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Where I'm using the \rule function in this example. I want to use a regular figure.

[image: How I want it to look...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `adjustbox` with `export` option. Then `valign` is available as a key to `\includegraphics`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
        &                   $\downarrow$                   &              \\
        $\rightarrow$ & \includegraphics[valign=c,width=3cm]{example-image-a} & $\leftarrow$ \\
        &                    $\uparrow$                    &
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And another option is to use `raisebox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
        &                   $\downarrow$                   &              \\
        $\rightarrow$ &
            \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}} & $\leftarrow$ \\
        &                    $\uparrow$                    &
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

To be precise, this should be (thanks to Manuel)

```
\raisebox{\dimexpr-0.5\height+\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
```

Comment: Perfect... Just perfect. Exactly what I've been trying to achieve. :D Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, the correct value would be `\dimexpr-0.5\height+\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax`

Comment: @Manuel Right, next level of procrastination, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well `\rule` has an optional argument to adjust the vertical alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lcr}
      &                   $\downarrow$                   &              \\
      $\rightarrow$ & \rule[-2cm]{4cm}{4cm} & $\leftarrow$ \\
      &                    $\uparrow$                    &
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: rule with lift]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I only used the rule command just to add something with large dimension in the table. I'm including figures instead of using black box.

I'm sorry, I should've make that clear.